# Возможно ли убрать отступы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Пример кода:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так, как одно изображение больше другого, то получаются ужасные отступы во второй колонке. Можно ли как-то это пофиксить через *Bootstrap*?

Или, что можно с этим сделать чтобы изображение было ровно под другим изображением и не имело отступа?

p.s обязательно изображения должны быть разного размера, т.е вариант подогнать все `div` под один размер отпадает.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```